# FreeIPA automount home directory prevents local user home directory creation

Tags: rhel, mount, nfs, automounting, freeipa

I have set up FreeIPA as IDM software for my network and successfully configured a Kerberos aware NFS server and Kerberos aware NFS clients.
When a user logs into a machine, it's user directory on the NFS server is automatically mounted via autofs from `nfs:/srv/nfs/home/userdir` to `/home/userdir` on the local machine.

I am facing the problem that when I need to create a local user on one machine, like the git user, that I cannot as the **root** user create a new home directory for the git user under `/home/git`, because it says `useradd: cannot create directory /home/git`

My auto.home map configuration is the following: `* nfs:/srv/nfs/home/&` and when I log in as any user, only the user's home directory is mounted under `/home`
And my auto.master map has the following entry: `/home auto.home`

the output from `mount` is the following:

```
auto.home on /home type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=6,pgrp=651,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,indirect,pipe_ino=15731)
nfs:/srv/nfs/home/userdir on /home/userdir type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=524288,wsize=524288,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=krb5,clientaddr=10.110.29.100,local_lock=none,addr=10.110.29.107)
```

I omitted unnecessary information about other file system and devices.

getfacl for the home directory returns:

```
file: home
owner: root
group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

Now, my question is, is this setup preventing my local root account from creating a local home directory on my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your current setup prevents you from creating a local home directory for a local user under `/home`... because you have defined `/home` as being an automount map of NFS mount points. Since NFS is Kerberos-aware, the user would need at least a Kerberos keytab to access a NFS-mounted home directory, and that keytab would be stored... within the user's home directory. That would seem to be a bit of a chicken/egg problem.

But the home directory for a local user named `git` does not need to be under `/home`: it could just as well be at `/home.local/git`, for example.

Since you've tagged this question with `rhel` and RHEL uses SELinux by default, you'll probably need to know that you will have to apply appropriate SELinux labels to both the actual home directory **and its parent directory**.

If you wish to make `git`'s home directory be `/home.local/git`, you'll need to first prepare SELinux labels as follows:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t home_root_t -f d /home.local
semanage fcontext -a -t user_home_dir_t -f d '/home.local/[̂^/]+'
semanage fcontext -a -t user_home_t '/home.local/[^/]+/.+'
mkdir /home.local
restorecon -rv /home.local
```

In other words, `/home.local` will get `home_root_t`, each directory immediately under it will get `user_home_dir_t`, and all files and directories deeper than that will get `user_home_t`. Similar labeling rules already exist for the regular `/home`.

After this, you could create the `git` user:

```
useradd -d /home.local/git -m [any other options] git
```

Or if the user already exists and only the home directory creation failed, you could modify its home directory path and manually create the actual home directory:

```
usermod -d /home.local/git git
cp -a /etc/skel /home.local/git
chown -R git: /home.local/git
chmod 700 /home.local/git  # or according to requirements
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Would there be a possible configuration of autofs to make it possible to mount NFS shares under /home and keeping local directories there as well?

Comment: Sadly, I don't see any realistic configuration that would allow that. It might be technically possible by making each user a separate automount entry instead of a single indirect automount map covering all the users, but that would be an administration nightmare unless you have just a few users.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think I will most likely implement what you have stated in your answers, but I have one more question about an alternate approach. I could set up a git user in FreeIPA and add it's home directory to the nfs server, would that be a possible approach? I can already see problems with the git user getting it's keytab, but what do you think about that?

Comment: Except for the already-mentioned keytab issue, I don't see any other problems with that approach. Unless your use of `git` is particularly heavy or your network connection to the NFS server is unusually slow (bandwidth and latency), I don't see an obvious reason why the git repository would absolutely have to be local.